# How to specify OVERWRITE to writeAsText in Apache Flink Streaming 0.10.0?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a method in scala

`counts.writeAsText(path_to_file)`

It throws an exception when file already exists and suggests to specify 
`File or directory already exists. Existing files and directories are not overwritten in NO_OVERWRITE mode. Use OVERWRITE mode to overwrite existing files and directories.`. But I have not found a method in DataStream class that accepts `org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.WriteMode`. There is only a signature that accepts Long for milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala API is currently missing an overload with the respective `WriteMode` parameter. This is a bug and will be fixed.

For the meantime, you can always control the default overwrite behaviour of Flink via the `fs.overwrite-files` configuration parameter. If you set this parameter to `fs.overwrite-files: true` in your `flink-conf.yaml`, then writing to a file will always overwrite.

The status of the corresponding JIRA issue can be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2622).

Answer (score 2):

Just a note: this has now been fixed. You can call `.writeAsText(filePath, org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE)`